# Limit Child-Text to Column Size of child in Flutter

Tags: flutter, text, width

I want to make an image preview gallery like this. The height for the image is fixed to 150px using SizedBox. So I do not know the actual width of the image, depends on its aspect ratio.

[image]

Now, I want to have a description text, which I add as a column:

```
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 150,
                        child: Image.file(
                           File(artifacts[index].localartifactPath!),
                           fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text("Hello everyone this is my text",
                          maxLines: 2,
                          softWrap: true,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall)
                      ]),
```

But I do not want that the text is longer in width than the image, if the text is too long, it shall break into a second line and if still to long, it should use the ellipsis....

[image]

Is there any way to tell the Text widget not be longer (set constraints) in width than the Image widget?
Thanks!